# C# - Getting int value from ComboBox object property

Tags: c#, object, properties, combobox

I'm using Windows Forms. Is there way to get `new_object.number_prop` value from the object currently selected in `comboBox1`? Preferably without using the `comboBox1` indexes. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I've been looking for a solution for a while now.

```
sampleObject new_object = new sampleObject();
new_object.text_prop = "sample text";
new_object.number_prop = 3;

comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, new_object);

class sampleObject
{
    public string text_prop {get; set; }
    public int number_prop {get; set; }
    public override string ToString();
    {
        return text_prop;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Grant Winney, edited the class in my example. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you are talking about this:

```
var selectedObject = (sampleObject) comboBox1.SelectedItem;
var value = selectedObject.number_prop;
```

Also please note, that `object` is reserved word (as alias to `Object` class) in C#.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this.

```
object new_object = new object();
new_object.text_prop = "sample text";
new_object.number_prop = 3;

comboBox1.Items.Insert(0, new_object);
comboBox1.ValueMember = "number_prop";
comboBox1.DisplayMember = "text_prop"

class SomeObject
{
    public string text_prop {get; set; }
    public int number_prop {get; set; }
    public override string ToString();
    {
        return text_prop;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the valueitem of combobox to "number_prop" and displayitem to "text_prop"